# Odoo 8 interface not displaying in full height after log in

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, odoo

I am having a problem with Odoo 8 app interface to show full height after logging in successfully. I tried it in Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera, they all show the same thing; but shows well in Internet Explorer.

See image link below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW1mN.jpg

Comment: Check your addons path, is it all correctly set.

Comment: @Hardik, i am new in this. Please how do i check the addons path

Comment: I think, the way you are saying that you don't know where is the addons path, that means you would have net set or modified it, so less chance of problem occurring from it.

Comment: My Addons file is found in this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150202\server\openerp\addons in my windows system

Comment: Have you try to update your browser...??

Comment: Yes try @Mischievous suggestion... I think that could be the issue.

Comment: Yes, @Mischievous my Firefox version is 35.0.1. it is up to date

Comment: Then uninstall it and re-install browser and try again..... i think it would be solved..!!!

Comment: @Mischievous.Thanks for you reply.If i get you correctly you suggest i re-install the version 35.0.1 of my firefox? Also remember that i also said that it did not display correctly in Chrome and Opera broswer.

Comment: I have re-installed firefox version 35.0.1 but still do not solve it. I really don't no what else to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem. Then I logged out and created a new db, it started working then properly. Don't know why it happened but solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced it many times. It usually happens while installing a new module or upgrading a module with following issue(s)
1. any error/mistake made in **openerp**.py file while mentioning path for any specific file such as "qweb XML" files.
2. Any error/mistake in defining path of a file which is included in module such as path for JS, CSS files.
3. Access right issue on a file. File may not have read permission for odoo user

If you have recently added a new module in Odoo Addons, remove it from addons and then try, it will work.

Hope this Helps!